# The MACs of the device and the connection didn't match

Tags: nmcli

When using `nmcli connection up MyNetwork ifname wlan0` I get this error

```
 Error: device 'wlan0' not compatible with connection 'MyNetwork':The MACs of the device and the connection didn't match..
```

The interface used to activate the network was another one.
But how do I allow every interface to have access to that connection using that `nmcli` command?

Comment: Why don't you just create a new connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `nmcli`, the only available way to do what I wanted is actually creating a new connection for every interface.